# Pull data when cell value is selected

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I am Trying to pull data from part of a sheet to another part depending on if dirt level 22 value is filled in. Please see attached Picture, basically, the bottom section pulls data from rows above depending on if dirt level 19, 20, 21 or 22 is displayed. I have only used 22 in the image.

[image: Timesheet example]

Comment: filled in where? pull it how? what selection? what do you mean by "pull when selected"? share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output.

Comment: I Have shared the example. The numbers on the bottom of the picture are how i want the output. Example - If Row 7 has a value of 22 in the column headed dirt money, then i want the job number row 7 to copy to the bottom job number column, dirt money rate (22) to copy to the bottom (Rate) Column and time on the job, ie 2hrs on the monday = 0200 in the (Hours:Mins) Column at bottom of picture.

Answer (score 1):

- paste in **AH27** cell:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(O7:O21=22, VLOOKUP(22, O7:X21, {3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, 0), ), 
   "where Col8 is not null", 0))
  ```
- paste in **AT27** cell:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(O7:O21=22, 
   Y7:Y21+AC7:AC21+AE7:AE21+AG7:AG21+AI7:AI21+AK7:AK21, ), "where Col8 is not null", 0))
  ```